# Windows Phone 8.1 upload video to remote server using HTTP multipart form data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having trouble on a certain piece of a current project and feel like I'm stuck right now. I'm trying to do a video upload with an HTTP post and multipart form data.
I want to upload video file on server with json file. i am create a json file and json file upload successfully on server but then i add video file in multipart request both file not upload on server. I try to find some code on google but not success. please help me

Video Select From Video Hub Successfull (code of video select):-

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
        openPicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "UpdateVideo";//"UpdateProfilePicture";
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".3GP");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".MP4");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".WMV");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".AVI");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".MOV");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".3G2");
        openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
        view.Activated += view_Activated;

    }
    catch { }
}

public void view_Activated(CoreApplicationView sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.IActivatedEventArgs args1)
{
    FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;
    if (args != null)
    {
        if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;
        view.Activated -= view_Activated;
        VideoStorageFile = args.Files[0];
    }
}
```

Video Upload Code:-

```
public async void UploadVideo()
{
    try
    {
        videoUid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        getVideoJson();
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpMultipartFormDataContent entity = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
        IInputStream inputStream = await VideoFileJson.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
       IInputStream videoInputStream = await VideoStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        entity.Add(new HttpStreamContent(inputStream), VIDEO_FILE_NAME, VideoFileJson.Name);
        entity.Add(new HttpStreamContent(videoInputStream), "videoFile", VideoStorageFile.Name);
        entity.Add(new HttpStringContent(videoUid), name: "videoUid");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("Url"), entity);
        String receiveStream = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ToString();
        txtVideoDes.Text = receiveStream;
        MessageBox.Show("Successfull Submit");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the video and json file not upload on server. And also i am not sure i code is right or wrong because i am copy this code from google search.